# gridview adapter parent.getChildAt(position) returns nullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, broadcastreceiver

i have an download manager with gridview of downloadable items, after download completed i need to update gridview button to show user that download is finished so i used BroadcastReceiver that call adapter and inform it to show changes but i get nullPointerException error in parent.getChildAt(position). and i should say that i used same code for listview in a fragment and in an activity and it did worked perfectly but gridview there is some problem.  this is my adapter getview:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_special, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.pid); // title
    final TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price); // duration
    final TextView fileurl = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.furl); // fileurl
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); // thumb image

    final TextView refrenceid = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.dmrefrence); // refrence id

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PID));
    artist.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_NAME));
    duration.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_PRICE));
    fileurl.setText(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_FILEURL));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(AllProductsActivity.TAG_DESCRIPTION), thumb_image);

    final ImageButton pauseButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton); // image button

    final ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); // image button
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to download product
            final String dfileurl = fileurl.getText().toString();
            final String fname = artist.getText().toString();

            imageButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            pauseButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            SpecialFragment x = new SpecialFragment();

            long id = x.myClickdwnl(fname,dfileurl,pauseButton,activity.getApplicationContext());
            downloadIdToPositionMap.put(id, position);
            refrenceid.setText(Long.toString(id));

       }
    });
    /* Cancel Download */
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to download product
            final String dnid = refrenceid.getText().toString();
            pauseButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            imageButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            HomeFragment x = new HomeFragment();

            x.Canceldwnl(dnid,activity.getApplicationContext());

       }
    });

    if(this.isDownloadFinished(position)){
       //ViewTreeObserver tree = parent.getViewTreeObserver();

       View v = parent.getChildAt(position);
       ImageButton cancelButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
       ImageButton successButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.succButton);
       cancelButton.setVisibility( View.GONE );
       successButton.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

       for(int i=0; i<this.finishedDownloadPositions.size();i++){
           if(this.finishedDownloadPositions.get(i) == position){
               this.finishedDownloadPositions.remove(i);
           }
       }

    }

    return vi;
}
```

and my BroadcastReceiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver griddownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
       long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

       //((GridAdapter)  getActivity().getListAdapter()).setDownloadFinished(referenceId);
       GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
       adapter = (GridAdapter) gv1.getAdapter();
       //final GridAdapter adapter = (GridAdapter) ((GridView) getView()).getAdapter();

        adapter.setDownloadFinished(referenceId);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       // Ask the adapter to refresh the ListView
       //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      }
};//end of broadcast reciever
```

and logcat:

```
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.example.one.GridAdapter.getView(GridAdapter.java:123)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.GridView.fillSpecific(GridView.java:543)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1240)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1528)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-12 11:51:04.881: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: you don't want to act on the view itself directly, modify the underlying data and notify the adapter to refresh the view

Answer (score 0):

Try using the context instead of the getView() method.

```
  BroadcastReceiver griddownloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
   long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

   //((GridAdapter)  getActivity().getListAdapter()).setDownloadFinished(referenceId);
   GridView gv1 = (GridView) context.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
   adapter = (GridAdapter) gv1.getAdapter();
   //final GridAdapter adapter = (GridAdapter) ((GridView) getView()).getAdapter();

    adapter.setDownloadFinished(referenceId);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   // Ask the adapter to refresh the ListView
   //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
};//end of broadcast reciever
```

If this doesn't work let me know I have another idea

Comment: i tested context, no luck. again same error. "nullPointerException"